# email ending with .edu validation with rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, regex, rspec

In Hartl's tutorial, I am presented with the following RSpec code

```
 describe "when email format is invalid" do
    it "should be invalid" do
      addresses = %w[user@foo,com user_at_foo.org example.user@foo.
                     foo@bar_baz.com foo@bar+baz.com]
      addresses.each do |invalid_address|
        @user.email = invalid_address
        expect(@user).not_to be_valid
      end
    end
  end

  describe "when email format is valid" do
    it "should be valid" do
      addresses = %w[user@foo.COM A_US-ER@f.b.org frst.lst@foo.jp a+b@baz.cn]
      addresses.each do |valid_address|
        @user.email = valid_address
        expect(@user).to be_valid
      end
    end
  end
```

The first is to test for invalid emails, and the second is to test for valid emails. I understand most of what is presented to me, but now I want to tweak it so that only emails ending with .edu will be accepted. A few questions come to mind:

1. why are there both tests for valid and invalid? wouldn't any test that doesn't pass the valid be invalid, and vice versa?
2. I see that in the valid test, they are valid because the follow some "normal email" convention. Can is simply replace the .com and .org with .edu to achieve my goal?

I know regex expression pertaining the .edu rule, but I really want to learn RSPec instead of just glacing it through. Any suggestions would be appreciated!

Comment: You need to test that the validation function correctly passes valid emails, and also correctly rejects invalid emails. So you need two tests.

Comment: what is the existing regex you are having in your User model ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For emails ending in edu you need to add the following regex to your user.rb model.

something like this:

```
validates_format_of :email, :with => /\A([^@\s]+)@((?:[-a-z0-9]+\.)+edu)\z/i
```

> 1. why are there both tests for valid and invalid? wouldn't any test that
>      doesn't pass the valid be invalid, and vice versa?

The tests are written keeping in mind the rspec be_valid. When a User object is created with values which are not validated. The object on saving returns false. Rspec check if there are any errors on saving.

You can also do this.

Create an object of User.

```
@user = User.new
```

Suppose in your User model you have :

```
validates :email, :presence => true
```

then try to save this `@user`

```
@user.save
```

It wont save. You can check what is the error by :

```
@user.errors
```

> 1. I see that in the valid test, they are valid because the follow some
>      "normal email" convention. Can is simply replace the .com and .org
>      with .edu to achieve my goal?

Its not about an email convention. Its about the regex or validation you have in your User model

Answer (score 0):

1. The code you posted is testing code, not the validation function. It needs to test that the validation function passes valid addresses and rejects invalid addresses. If you only did one set of tests, you could not confirm both behaviors. For instance, if the validation function simply returned `true` for any input, and you only did the *when email format is valid* tests, you wouldn't know that it never rejects invalid emails.
2. After you change the model so it only considers `.edu` addresses to be valid, and you want to test it, you should move all the non-edu addresses into the list in the *when email format is invalid* block, and add some .edu addresses to the *when email format is valid* block.